# How to delete excessive rows in Excel

Tags: excel

This has been asked many times on the web and I have tried many of the solutions, however my problem still persists. If I use the scroll bar and go to the bottom of the sheet there are over 100,000 rows, which makes the scroll bar useless to navigate the actual data. I have tried to select a heap of rows and delete them but the number of total rows doesn't seem to diminish. If I press ctrl + enter + down arrow and select all of the rows and try to delete them I get an error come up saying I don't have enough resources.

Can anyone suggest another way to get rid of these cells so that I can navigate my data properly using the scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Excel gets confused as to where the UsedRange is.

Try this code, see if it helps:

```
Sub ResetUsedRange()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lng As Long

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        lng = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Next
End Sub
```